# How to calculate depreciation?

Tags: calculation, financial-literacy, accounting, depreciation

I am not accountant and my question could be trivial but I will ask it.

Let's say that I bought a car that cost $50,000. The maintenance cost over 5 years is $25,000. The revenue of the car over 5 years is 35,000.
What is the current book value of the car after depreciation, if the car depreciate at 10% per year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After one year the book value would be $50,000 - $5,000 (10%) = $45,000.

After year two the book value would be $45,000 - $4,500 (10%) = $40,500.

And so on, until after the fifth year the book value would be approximately $29,524.50.

You basically deduct 10% off the new book value each over the 5 years.

Comment: So maintenance cost and revenue has nothing to do with the depreciation?

Comment: No they don't. If using the car for business the depreciation could be used as a deduction to reduce the tax you pay on the income produced through your business. The maintenance costs could also be used in the same way as a deduction to reduce the tax on the income produced.

Comment: So book value is the value of the car after detecting depreciation cost, right?

Comment: How about net book value?

Comment: Book value is what you can expect to get for the make/model of the car, that may be more or less than the depreciated value as well as more or less than what you can actually get -- there is no connection between any of them. Say some movie star goes on a rampage with a baseball bat, practically destroying the vehicle.  Your car may now be a collectors item, worth millions, while the book value says it's worth 750 (extremely poor condition), and the depreciated value says it's worth 1250.

Comment: There is a distinction between *tax* depreciation and *economic* depreciation.  Tax depreciation is the amount of money the federal government will let you deduct as depreciation and is basically a way to subsidize certain kinds of assets.  Economic depreciation is the actual amortized cost of replacement over the asset's useful life.  Assets can even be "fully depreciated" from a tax perspective and still have a useful life.